# How to convert unicode to symbol C

Tags: c, unicode, converters, symbols

How to convert Unicode Hexadecimal for print/write?

Input:

```
0x00DF
```

Desired Output:

```
ß
```

Symbol:

http://www.unicodemap.org/details/0x00DF/index.html

Comment: The C standard does not cover Unicode. Any solution will be platform dependent.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: C11 has some Unicode support.  See *Unicode utitilities `<uchar.h>`* which is section 7.28 of ISO/IEC 9899:2011, and also section 6.4.5 *String Literals* which covers the `u`, `U`, and `u8` prefixes to string literals.

Comment: Which code set are you using for input and output?  That will largely determine how you generate the LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler What about output?

Comment: As I said 'some Unicode support'. Input and output are platform and locale dependent. If the output expects ISO 8859-1, you send a single byte 0xDF; if it expects UTF-8, you send two bytes 0xC3 0x95; if it expects UTF-16LE, you send two bytes 0x9F 0x00; if it expects UTF-16BE, you send two bytes 0x00 0x9F, etc -- as I'm sure you're aware, in general terms even if not of the exact byte codes for U+009F. I was objecting to your blanket 'C does not cover Unicode' statement, which is not precisely accurate for C11. If you said 'C does not cover display of Unicode', I'd have not made any comment.

Answer (score 2):

If your C implementation and your terminal support unicode, then

```
$ cat tst.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    printf ("\u00DF\n");
    return 0;
}
$ cc tst.c
$ ./a.out
ß
$
```

This is on FreeBSD with clang and xterm and `LC_CTYPE=de_DE.UTF-8` (but any *.UTF-8 will do).

Comment: Might also want to add he should look up the use of `wchar_t` for storing unicode values in variables. +1

Comment: If using UTF-8, `wchar_t` is neither necessary nor desirable.